# How do I pivot my table with different headers?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table 'TABLE_COUNT' as follows:

```
METRIC        COUNT 
SOURCE_A        10
MART_A        10
SOURCE_B        20
MART_B        20
```

I used the following script :

```
select * from (  select METRIC, COUNT
FROM dbo.TABLE_COUNT
where METRIC in ('SOURCE_A','MART_A')) src
PIVOT
(AVG(COUNT) FOR METRIC IN ([SOURCE_A],[MART_A]) )piv
union all
select * from (  select METRIC, COUNT
FROM dbo.TABLE_COUNT
where METRIC in ('SOURCE_B','MART_B',)) src
PIVOT
(AVG(COUNT) FOR METRIC IN ([SOURCE_B],[MART_B]) )piv;
```

This is the result I get:

```
SOURCE_A    MART_A 
10                10
null           null
```

This is the result I get:

```
SOURCE_A    MART_A
10             10
null          null
```

But I would like to project it this way:

```
   SOURCE   MART
A   10       10
B   20       20
```

Answer (score 0):

You can alias the fields in your first union statement.

```
select SOURCE = SOURCE_A, MART = MART_A from (  select METRIC, COUNT
FROM dbo.TABLE_COUNT
where METRIC in ('SOURCE_A','MART_A')) src
PIVOT
(AVG(COUNT) FOR METRIC IN ([SOURCE_A],[MART_A]) )piv
union all
select * from (  select METRIC, COUNT
FROM dbo.TABLE_COUNT
where METRIC in ('SOURCE_B','MART_B',)) src
PIVOT
(AVG(COUNT) FOR METRIC IN ([SOURCE_B],[MART_B]) )piv;
```

Comment: Thanks, the naming worked perfectly but nulls get populated in my third row like above.

Comment: That would indicate all values are null for one of your fields. Do you want to omit nulls or display 0 for null?

Answer (score 0):

This could be even simpler with a cross tabs query.

```
--Generate Sample data
CREATE TABLE #Sample(
    METRIC   varchar(50),     
    COUNT int);
INSERT INTO #Sample
VALUES
('SOURCE_A', 10),
('MART_A', 10),
('SOURCE_B', 20),
('MART_B', 20);
GO

--Solution
SELECT RIGHT( RTRIM( METRIC), 1),
    AVG( CASE WHEN METRIC LIKE 'SOURCE%' THEN [COUNT] END) AS SOURCE,
    AVG( CASE WHEN METRIC LIKE 'MART%' THEN [COUNT] END) AS MART
FROM #Sample
GROUP BY RIGHT( RTRIM( METRIC), 1);

GO
--Clean my database
DROP TABLE #Sample;
```

EDIT:
I guess it could also be done with pivot.

```
SELECT * 
FROM (  SELECT SUBSTRING( METRIC, 0, CHARINDEX( '_', METRIC)) AS MetricType, 
            RIGHT( RTRIM( METRIC), 1) AS MetricGroup, 
            COUNT
        FROM #Sample) src
PIVOT (AVG(COUNT) FOR MetricType IN ([SOURCE],[MART]) )piv;
```